# Problem with like button affecting all videos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyF6E.png)    check the img please

I have videos/video info /like button that is being dynamically shown via the code bellow
My issue is that although I've givven each video its own id, they are all being clicked and incremented when the user clicks the like button.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?
Am I approaching this problem the wrong way?
What do you suggest?

-Video are appended into this container

```
<div class="videos"><!--video skeleton dev-->
<section class ="video-section">
 
</section>
</div>                            <!--end of video skeleton devs-->
```

The array which contains video info:

- `src`: is the youtube embed " i frame data "
- `vcn`: video chanel name
- `vtl`: video title
- lkid: like key id
- iclkid: icon like key id

```
let javaScript = [{src: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/7UMuJMiNjSk",lkid:"vid1",iclkid:"false" , vcn: "Web Dev Simplified",vt:  "Every JavaScript Developer Has Made This Mistake With Functions"},{src:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/XF1_MlZ5l6M", lkid:"vid2",iclkid:"false" , vcn: "Web Dev Simplified",vt: "Learn JavaScript Event Listeners In 18 Minutes"},
  {src:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/s1XVfm5mIuU",lkid:"vid3",iclkid:"false" , vcn: "Web Dev Simplified",vt: "Learn JavaScript Array Reduce In 10 Minutes"}];
```

-The appending function:-

```
$(".batata").on("click", function () {  //   JAVASCRIPT RENDER
  console.log("js clicked")
javaScript.forEach((item, i) => {

  $(".video-section").append(`
        <article class ="video-container">              
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="${item.src}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     
     </a>
     <div class="video-bottom-section">
         <a href="#">       
             <img class="channel-icon" src="http:///unsplash.it/36/36?gravity=center" alt="Your Channel" /> 
         </a>
         <div class="video-details"> 
            <a href="#" class="video-channel-name">${item.vcn}</a>
            <a href="#" class="video-title"> ${item.vt} </a>
            <button class="fixButtons"onclick="showVideoOne()">View</button>

            <button class="fixButtonsCounter">
                <span class= ${item.iclkid}   id="iconThree"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></span>
                <span class = ${item.lkid}  id="countThree">0</span>
            </button>
         </div>  
     </div> 
    </article> `);
});
});
```

-Like button function:-

```
let thumbsUp = false;
$(document).on("click", () => {
  console.log("Farhan")
  if (!thumbsUp) {
    thumbsUp = true;
    let y = 1
    $(".icon55").html(`<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>`);       // how do i connect this ? with ${item.iclkid}
    $(".count55").text(1);
  } else {
    thumbsUp = false;
    let x = 1;
    $(".icon55").html(`<i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>`);     // how do i connect this ? with ${item.lkid}
    $(".count55").text(0);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```js
var items = [{
    src: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/7UMuJMiNjSk",
    lkid: "vid1",
    iclkid: "false",
    vcn: "Web Dev Simplified",
    vt: "Every JavaScript Developer Has Made This Mistake With Functions"
  }, {
    src: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/XF1_MlZ5l6M",
    lkid: "vid2",
    iclkid: "false",
    vcn: "Web Dev Simplified",
    vt: "Learn JavaScript Event Listeners In 18 Minutes"
  },
  {
    src: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/s1XVfm5mIuU",
    lkid: "vid3",
    iclkid: "false",
    vcn: "Web Dev Simplified",
    vt: "Learn JavaScript Array Reduce In 10 Minutes"
  }
];

$.each(items, function(index, value) {
  $(".video-section").append('<article class ="video-container"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + value.src + '" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></a><div class="video-bottom-section"><a href="#"><img class="channel-icon" src="http:///unsplash.it/36/36?gravity=center" alt="Your Channel" /></a><div class="video-details"><a href="#" class="video-channel-name">' + value.vcn + '</a><a href="#" class="video-title">' + value.vt + ' </a><button type="text" class="video" id="' + value.lkid + '">View-' + value.lkid + '</button><button type="text" class="fixButtonsCounter"><span class= ' + value.iclkid + ' id="iconThree"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></span><span class="counter"  id="counter-' + value.lkid + '">0</span></button></div></div> ');
})

var votes;
var id;
var counter = 0;
$('.videos').find('.counter').attr('js-vote', 0);


$(".video").on("click", function() {
  id = $(this).attr('id');
  counter = $(this).nextUntil('.fixButtonCounter').find('#counter-' + id + '').attr('js-vote');
  counter++;
  $(this).nextUntil('.fixButtonCounter').find('#counter-' + id + '').attr('js-vote', counter);
  votes = $(this).nextUntil('.fixButtonCounter').find('#counter-' + id + '').attr('js-vote');
  $(this).nextUntil('.fixButtonCounter').find('#counter-' + id + '').text(votes);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="videos">
  <section class="video-section">
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: thoes ids are used for css styling

Comment: If you check my likebutton functionality I have a major issue there <br/>
 ` $(".icon55").html(<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>); // how do i connect this ? with ${item.iclkid} $(".count55").text(1); } else { thumbsUp = false; let x = 1; $(".icon55").html(<i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>); // how do i connect this ? with ${item.lkid} $(".count55").text(0); 
`
I am not sure how to tell the function to target each like button by its different

Comment: I added an img to clarify my problem further, located at top of the question

the ids are used by all button, they are only used for styling the button
each button is givven a class via the video array to make it unique

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe this will help you a little bit. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much!

I will try this and come back to you, " to be honest half the code you wrote is alian to me "

Comment: May I ask what does this code mean?

$("[id^=vid]")

Comment: Ist means all id‘s which starts with the word vid.

Comment: I had to modify the code a bit in the append part, the button wasnt working with 
' + value.vcn + ' 
' + value.vt + '
"' + value.lkid + '"
 ' + value.iclkid + '
 ' + value.lkid + '
' + value.lkid + '   
not sure why, but it worked with the old
${item.vcn}
${item.vt}
           <button class="fixButtons"onclick="showVideoOne()">View</button>
${item.lkid}
${item.lkid}
${item.iclkid}
${item.lkid}
${item.lkid}

only two remaining issues, they appear to be sharing the same counter, liking 1 video then liking another continues with the old value from another video

Comment: I think I have to modify my array of objects to be something like this

let javaScript = [video1: {src: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/7UMuJMiNjSk",lkid:"vid1",iclkid:"false" , vcn: "Web Dev Simplified",vt:  "Every JavaScript Developer Has Made This Mistake With Functions"}

Else I am not sure how the button function will distinguish that each video should have its own values

Comment: So I did it :-) updated the Solution above. Just test it :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot,  it appears to me that this code is at least 1 month of practice above my current understanding. I will keep it aside until I fully understand how it works :)

Thank you so much for helping out.

Comment: I changed the the code. Now the youtube videos are working :-) Just make console.log after each step. So you see what is in the variable. You will understand this. I'm sure :-) I made also a jsfiddle for you. So you can play a little bit arround with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/ktu5dp7f/132/

Comment: Roger that, I will study it <Promise></Promise>